# Clojure : why does this writer consume so much heap space?

Tags: clojure, file-processing

I have a 700 mb XML file that I process from a records tree to an EDN file.

After having do all the processing, I finally have a lazy sequence of hashmaps that are not particularely big (at most 10 values).

To finish, I want to write it to a file with

```
(defn write-catalog [catalog-edn]
  (with-open [wrtr (io/writer "catalog-fr.edn")]
    (doseq [x catalog-edn]
      (.write wrtr (prn-str x)))))
```

I do not understand the problem because `doseq` is supposed to do not retain the head of the sequence in memory.

My final output `catalog` is of type `clojure.lang.LazySeq`.

I then do

```
(write-catalog catalog)
```

Then memory usage is grinding and I have a GC overhead error at around 80mb of file writter with a XmX of 3g.

I tried also with a `doseq` + `spit` and no `prn-str`, same thing happen.

Is this a normal behaviour ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly the memory leaks due to the `catalog` values realization (google "head retention"). When your `write-catalog` realizes items one by one, they are kept in memory (obviously you're `def`'fing `catalog` somewhere). To fix this you may try to avoid keeping your catalog in a variable, instead pass it to the `write-catalog` at once. Like if you parse it from somewhere (which i guess is true, considering your previous question), you would want to do:

`(write-catalog (transform-catalog (get-catalog "mycatalog.xml")))`

so huge intermediate sequences won't eat all your memory

Hope it helps.

Comment: You are right, I forgot I noticed this. If I understand well, the garbage collector cannot release the seq as long as the var defined is bound. I consume now not much memory. Thanks !!